# "#include <asm/io.h>" causes "error: asm/io.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, hardware-interface, gentoo, parallel-port

I am using gentoo and trying to compile a program to control the bits on the parallel port. It has this line near the top of it:

```
#include <asm/io.h>
```

And when I try to use gcc on it, it produces this output:

> port.c:4:20: error: asm/io.h: No such file or directory

"locate asm/io.h" yeilds (among other things):

> /usr/src/linux-2.6.32-gentoo/arch/x86/include/asm/io.h

So I have the header file, but it's not finding it?
Why is this not working?

Comment: It's not in your default include path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure if you are the author of the program or you're just trying to compile a program you got from someone, but [looks like](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/8832) `#include <asm/io.h>` should be replaced with `#include <sys/io.h>`. See the results of [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=asm%2Fio.h+sys%2Fio.h) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

**Never** use the code/headers in `/usr/include/asm`.  Use the headers in `/usr/include/sys` instead.

What you are doing by using `/usr/include/asm/` is building your code against a specific revision of the Kernel headers.  This is subject to breakage when the kernel headers change.  By linking to the other location, you will link to a more stable form of the headers in glibc, which will refer to the kernel headers as needed.  That's why there's a large complex of `#ifdef ... #endif` lines peppered all in the headers.

Trust me, all the tools you need for bit-fiddling with the parallel ports will be in `/usr/include/sys/io.h`, since probably all you're going to be using are direct `readb()` and `writeb()` calls to the appropriate `/dev/lpX` device.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
gcc -I/usr/src/linux-2.6.32-gentoo/arch/x86/include xyx
```

where xyz is the file you're trying to compile.

This tells the compiler where to look for include files.
You can have many -I options if your include files are in different locations, like this

```
gcc -I/usr/src/linux-2.6.32-gentoo/arch/x86/include -I/usr/src/some/Dir xyx
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed that problem. The only problem now is that that file pulls in a bunch of other files, one of which (asm-generic/ioctls.h) simply doesn't exist on my dard drive...the sad part is that /usr/include/asm-generic/ioctl.h is present. Typo in header perhaps?

Comment: See my answer. Looks like very old code, and trying to get it to work on a modern linux kernel might be a lot of trouble. May I know what library/code it is?

Comment: It is parcon, from http://bigasterisk.com/projects/parallel. While there is a binary on the site, I don't want to use that because I want to be able to customize the program to suit my needs. Anyway, I added a symlink from ioctls.h to ioctl.h in /usr/include/asm-generic, plus an -I/usr/src/linux/include switch on the command line, and now am getting a bunch of errors in io.h regarding syntax errors and undefined variables. Maybe the symlink was not to the right file?

Comment: As I said in my answer, try replacing `asm/io.h` with `sys/io.h`. http://homebrewtechnology.blogspot.com/2009/03/internet-controled-car-v2-parallel-port.html seems to suggest it works.

Comment: Also, you can't just link similarly named files like this and assume it will work :-).

Comment: Changing to sys/io.h worked great without any other hacking. Thank you!

Comment: I don't get all those "thank you"s and still 0 points to the answer thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the path. On the gcc command line:

```
gcc -I/usr/src/linux-2.6.32-gentoo/arch/x86/include ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -I/usr/src/linux-2.6.32-gentoo/arch/x86/include to your compile command line.

Answer (score 0):

This answer maybe not for your condition, but I hope it can help others.

For me, when I try to make my driver, I met same problem, at last, I fixed it by correct my `Makefile` from:

```
obj-m += t.o
KDIR:=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
MAKE:=make


t-objs:  main.o base.o

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules  
clean:  
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

to

```
obj-m += t.o
KDIR:=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
MAKE:=make


t-objs:=  main.o base.o

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules  
clean:  
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```