# How to access Parallel port in Linux

Tags: linux, parallel-port, hardware-port

On my Linux machine (Debian Wheezy), I tried to access the parallel port by `request_region()` but it failed because the system had already loaded the kernel module `parport`...

So, I `rmmod` the modules `lp`, `ppdev`, `parport_pc` and `parport`. Then, I could successfully insert my module.

However, from the base address `inb()` returned `0xff`, no matter what value was written.

Before `rmmod` those module from kernel, I could wrote and read this register. Then I blacklisted those module from being loaded at system start up, and I could read and write these registers and my module also worked. It seems that the `clearup` function of `parport_pc` did something that made the hardware unusable. (At least the status of the port is not the same as it was before the module loaded).

My question is why, and what should I do to recover the port instead of reload `parport_pc` ?

Comment: Why do you need a kernel module to access the parallel port? Can you use the interface provided by Linux?

Comment: My intention is to get better understanding of the hardware, so I want to access it at the lowest level by means of method as simple as it could be. Yes I can use parport provided by Linux but the question is I can't unuse it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C to write a small program that will read and write directly from/to the pins on the parallel port by way of the outb and inb functions.  Then, you can simply call the C program from the command line of shelling from some other script.  Usually, (by default) address 0x378 is the address of the parallel port LPT0 in memory, so you it's just a matter of using inb and outp to read/write to this address.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <asm/io.h>

#define base 0x378   //LPT0

//to compile:  gcc -O parport.c -o parport
//after compiling, set suid:  chmod +s parport   then, copy to /usr/sbin/


int main(void) {
  if(ioperm(base,1,1)) 
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open parallel port"), exit(1);

  outb(255,base);  //set all pins hi
  sleep(5); 
  outb(0,base);    //set all pins lo

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But probably you don't quite get what I mean. I know it's possible to access parallel port from user space. (and from kernel space too.) But if you rmmod parport_pc firstly, I did tried, this program could not work correctly.

Comment: I had to modify 1 include, from asm/io.h to sys/io.h
according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4152034/1671029 we now link to way more stable kernel headers

Answer (score 2):

Some driver mods have blocked your access to parallel port.
Edit the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file and add the following lines, then reboot your linux.

```
blacklist ppdev
blacklist lp
blacklist parport_pc
blacklist parport
```

And if cups is installed, you should modify /etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf:

```
#lp
#ppdev
#parport_pc
```

Here is some details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27423675/4350106